# caret navigation (getting a text cursor) in Google Chrome?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, vimperator, keyboard-navigation, conkeror

I use Google Chrome on OSX. Is there a way, within the browser, to get a text cursor that will allow me to navigate through text, selecting and copying text using only the keyboard?

I've looked at Vimium, Conkeror, and Vimperator, but as far as I can tell, they allow you to use the keyboard to navigate web pages (scrolling, visiting links) but don't provide a text cursor.

Is this possible?

Update: I have learned that this is called caret browsing or caret navigation. Is this possible in Chrome?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recently Google Chrome introduced built-in functionality to browser with caret, just press <kbd>F7</kbd> or go to *Settings* > *Advanced* > *Accessibility* and then turn on "Navigate pages with a text cursor" switch.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, I thought I was crazy and this text cursor thing had always been there, but now I'm realizing my 3 year old turned it on last week while button mashing on my keyboard!

Comment: I am convinced it was always possible to caret browse text on webpages, and that was removed without word some time ago. But I have been struggling so long without it since that I cannot be sure it was not a mere dream.

Answer (score 10):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open the console.
2. Enter the following into the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   document.body.contentEditable=true
   ```

Now you get a cursor and can even edit the whole page.

Comment: Whilst this is useful (+1), it is very different to caret browsing. The content is literally editable and is no longer navigable (anchors are not active, etc.).

Comment: @w3d: Humm, you're right. Let me see if I can offer something better :D

Comment: @w3d: Seems like most people online only offer text selection as a replacement for caret browsing, I doubt that's what you want either. The best I could offer would be to turn content editing off while the mouse cursor is inside the page (move cursor to address bar to show the caret): `$("html").hover(function(){document.body.contentEditable=false;},function(){document.body.contentEditable=true;});`

Comment: The only problem with this way is that I also couldn't find a keyboard-only way to select "Console", when opening Ctrl+Shift+J.
EDIT: Weird enough, it seems Ctrl+Shift+J sometimes open in Elements tab (and then I can't TAB to Console), and sometimes opens directly on Console (as wished). Thank you for the hint anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/vimperator/) has caret browsing. The default keybind for it is <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: And how does that apply to enabling caret browsing in Chrome?

Comment: >I've looked at Vimium, Conkeror, and Vimperator, but as far as I can tell, they [...] don't provide a text cursor.
Vimperator does provide a text cursor.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm a bit confused how he got it to work in Chrome though.

Answer (score 3):

So far, it is not yet implemented or planned:[source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46282). You can star this feature request and remain updated.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome extension, [Caret Browsing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret-browsing/fklpgenihifpccgiifchnihilipmbffg) supports mode switching between the caret and the normal browsing.

[image]

I think many people'd like the caret navigation back/forward as well, but it hasn't supplied the feature yet.

Comment: Some guy down voted, kidding ?