# Make the Chrome text cursor render statically rather than blink?

Tags: google-chrome, text-cursor, caret

If I'm arrowkey-browsing within a text field or textarea, I only know half the time where I am. I have to pause and wait for the blinking to reappear before I can go on. That is mildly frustrating.

For instance, Sublime Text allows the text cursor to blink in various ways ("smooth", "phase", "blink") – or appear statically ("solid") and never blink. Is there a way to achieve that last state? Maybe some secret hidden Chrome:flag thing?

I am ***not*** talking about [caret browsing](https://superuser.com/questions/563460/caret-navigation-getting-a-text-cursor-in-google-chrome). I mean only those occurrances where a text cursor genuinely appears – like in a text form field.

Comment: Try to install [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) with [this theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/125112/google-docs-disable-cursor-blink).

Comment: That seems a bit overkill just for that one request … — But I want to give it a try when I'm back home.